# Laravel: Order by on join?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `users` and then I have a table called `user_stats`, the stats table holds the amount of time this user has been online. I'm trying to create a collection of the top 10 most online users by ordering by the `online_time` column in the `user_stats` but I need to pass a collection of the `users` table models, so that I can call generic columns like `username` and `motto`

The users

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Database\User\UserStats;
use Auth;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        protected $table = 'users';
        public $timestamps = true;
        protected $guarded = ['id'];

        public function getStats() {
            return UserStats::where('id', $this->id)->first();
        }
    }
```

And the stats

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class UserStats extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'user_stats';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

If it was just users, I would do it like this

```
User::orderBy('online_time', 'DESC')->limit($limit)->get();
```

But when `online_time` belongs to the stats table, its a bit more difficult.

Comment: Why not `User::join(...)->orderBy('online_time')`?

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between `User` and `UserStat` is 1:1 you can:

```
class UserStats
{
    ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

and get:

```
UserStats::with('user')->orderBy('online_time', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();
```